# Powershell_out not saving powershell output to a variable in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to test PowershellOut in Chef in order to get some values from PS code and then save it into a ruby variable in order to use it within chef code. I have created a very simple scenario in order to test this:

Chef code:

```
::Chef::Resource::PowershellScript.send(:include,    Chef::Mixin::PowershellOut)

    testPO = <<-EOH
  $varo = "new22"
  $varo
EOH

newvar = powershell_out(testPO)

directory "C:\\Users\\Foo\\Desktop\\#{newvar}" do

  action :delete
end
```

There are no "red" errors, however I've found out that there is some sort of error code within the variable itself:

> directory[C:\Users\foo\Desktop#"<"Mixlib::ShellOut:0x58a8140">"]

Answer (score 1):

You should try `newvar = powershell_out(testPO).stdout.chomp()`.

powershell_out works like shell_out which is better documented [here](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout/blob/master/README.md).

Quote from the Readme above:

> **Simple Shellout**   Invoke find(1) to search for .rb files:
>
> ```
> require 'mixlib/shellout'
> find = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("find . -name '*.rb'")
> find.run_command
> ```
>
> If all went well, the results are on stdout
>
> ```
> puts find.stdout
> ```

Keep in mind in chef recipe you don't need to require 'mixlib/shellout' as chef already did it for you and `shell_out` is a a kind of helper for `Mixlib::ShellOut.new()`.

Your method to include powershell_out in the recipe sounds fine (I'm unsure it is neede but that depends on your version of chef client)